# Rails, finder in model (using collect) or in controller (iterating and using push).  Which is more efficent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, loops

which way below is more efficient to accomplish this task. I want to loop through a model, check if a list made up of integer vals associated with each model_id is greater than 0. If it is then take the corresponding models into a list of models.

```
@models = Model.find(:all).collect{|m| m }.reject{ |i| modellist[i.id] < 1 }
```

or like this

```
finalModels = []
Model.find_each do |model|
  if modellist[model.id] > 0 #edited
  #if modellist[model.id] != 0
    finalModels.push( model )
  end
end
@models = finalModels
```

Im leaning towards the second approach, but im not sure. Maybe some insight into how .collect and .reject works to see how efficient it is.

- **Edit**

My model is called Picture. modellist (or pList) contains data similar to this.

```
[nil,nil,nil,3,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,
nil,nil,7,nil,nil,nil,0,nil,nil,nil,0,0,nil,nil,1,3]
```

I the index number of pList corresponds to the picture id for this. So i need to find pics where pList[picture id] is greater than 0.

- **Edit**

Used Benoit Garrets answer. What i had to do was make sure that pList was declared by pList = Hash.new and not pList = []. the exact query i used was

```
@pictures = Picture.find(pList.select {|k, v| v > 0}.keys)
```

Comment: `@models = Model.find(:all).collect{|m| m }.reject{ |i| modellist[i.id] < 1 }` is better written as: `@models = Model.all.reject{ |i| modellist[i.id] < 1 }`

Comment: `.collect{|m|m}` is not necessary. How's `modellist` or `pList` stored?

Comment: Both ways are inefficient, loading the entire table. `find_each` will lock up your db slightly less if the table is large, but takes longer. The only correct solution so far is also the only answer with 0 votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `modellist` and `pList` already exist and are `Hash`, you could filter them before and use `find` with an array:

```
@models = Model.find(modellist.reject {|k, v| v < 1} .keys)
```

Same thing with your second example:

```
@pictures = Picture.find(pList.reject {|k, v| v > 0} .keys)
```

This way, you won't be looping over your entire database.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do this in the database directly:

```
@models = Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["id in (?)", modellist.select{ |i| i && i > 0}])
```

Or the shorter version:

```
@models = Model.find(modellist.select{ |i| i && i > 0})
```

Comment: looks good, but i get the error undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass , this is probably because i have a bunch of nil vals within the list, do you think there is a way to add a check if it is not nil, then i do this part of the query

Comment: Just replace `i > 0` with `i && i > 0`

Comment: the first sol'n gives no results when it should be 2 results. The second gives -- Couldn't find all Pictures with IDs (1, 2) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2) -- maybe this is because your function took only a list of when the criteria is passed (so it would look for index 1 and 2, when my pic ids can be as high as 200, with nil vals in between for non-existent pics)

Comment: is modellist an array of integers, or is it something else? It'd be easier to diagnose if you update your question with the actual code you're using (e.g. Picture instead of Model) and a sample of what modellist might contain.

Comment: Well both errors would indicate that your database doesn't actually have any pictures with ids of 1 and 2, which are the only two numbers in your `pList` that are greater than zero. Are you sure those two records actually exist?

Comment: know those records were deleted, @pictures = Picture.all.reject{ |i| modellist[i.id] < 1 } renders the correct pictures, which shows me that pList gives the correct val's for pictures ids

Comment: @DylanMarkow The array is id-indexed; `select` returns an array of useless values (not ids). Adding or removing values from the array messes up the ids.

Comment: i changed pList = [] to pList = Hash.new. Then changed your query to @models = Model.find(modellist.select{ |i| i && i > 0}.keys) , it works

Answer (score 1):

Why not map the modellist array and pull out the indexes/keys with values not equal to 0, and pass that array of ids to the Model finder?

(would rustle up some code, but am not in front of my pc)

Answer (score 1):

Kinda silly to store the values in an id-indexed array, because you can't manipulate it without changing the indices and putting all the ids out of whack.

```
ids = []
modellist.each_index{|i| ids << i if modelist[i] > 0}
@models = Model.find ids
```

If modellist was a hash instead:

```
@models = Model.find modellist.select{|k,v| v > 0}.keys
```

Comment: i could've used either yours or benoit garrets. I just had change the if statement to if (modellist[i] && modelist[i]>0). for the second, for some reason i didn't know to declare the difference between making an array and hash. i had to change my array modellist =[] to modellist = Hash.new , then everythings perfect. thanks

Comment: No prob. I got rid of my PHP habits the same way.